# htacess seo friendly not working proplery

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo

I am trying to make seo friendly url for my page http://www.jobslamp.com/jobsbystate.php?s=af3d1405&st=Kerala . I have tried some htacess code before , but then the designs are lost. Could u plz suggest the proper htacess code to achieve this . I would like to get an url like http://www.jobslamp.com/jobsbystate.php/af3d1405&st/Kerala

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you're linking to CSS or javascript using relative URI's instead of absolute URI's. You can either make all of your links absolute by adding a leading slash (for example):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" type="text/css">
```

Or you can define the URI base in the header of your pages by adding:

```
<base href="/">
```

or whatever the base should be.